# Problem in showing progress bar while executing insert statement in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

Problem in showing progress bar while executing insert statement in android. While 
calling this try block its showing blank screen. Not even xml is called while executing this statement.

```
try {
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    try {                           
         db.execSQL(str);                   
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Thanks,
Yuvaraj

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is running in the UI thread - so a UI action will only happen after this code has run. Put the insert into background (e.g. via `AsyncTask`).

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask with ProgressDialog bounded, like it is done [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?cat=6&lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use Handler  or AsyncTask to handle operations in background

Go through the following link

http://saeedsiam.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-look-into-android-thread.html

Comment: I tried both AsyncTask  and progress dialog but when I used those the values are not inserted in the table. Please suggest me with sample code.